# Link Visual studio with compiled library on cygwin

Tags: visual-studio, cygwin, shared-libraries, cross-platform

I compiled shared library (.dll) using cygwin on windows, i have a project on visual studio which i would like to link with the (.dll) from cygwin, is that possible ?

Comment: No, you can't as the two build systems use different assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend matzeri's response [FAQ says](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.msvcrt-and-cygwin) that this is impossible.